# use jquery's ajax to post binary data and use a webservice to consume it

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, binary

I'd like to be able to post binary data to a webservice.

I imagine it's going to look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/MyPage.aspx/DoStuff',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: // some content type ?
        data: rawData // may be string or object, depending on format above.
});
```

and in MyPage.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DoStuff(object data) // some particular input type?
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a hidden iframe and post your form (with or without intervention from jQuery) to it, and then handle the response in the iframe. You can do that for either a single form field (file field), or the whole form.

I think jQuery Form plugin does this for you. Search Stackoverflow a bit and I'm sure you'll find a lot about iframe posting.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a file on your web server named "webservice.aspx" which then handles you're request. Then by using get or post you could tell the code behind what action to execute.

For an example, if you make lookup if the action parameter was set in the webservice.aspx.cs file and then made a switch on it. Then make you're cases and make it call a functions.

dataType could then just be plain old html or a json in order to validate if the ajax was successfully executed. Not in terms of the actual ajax status but the execution of the code.